# Component super class?

Tags: java, entity-component

I have recently been programming an Entity Component System in Java for a small game that I am working on. From what I have tested, it works rather well however I question the component part. I currently have an *Entity* class that stores subclasses of  *Component* in a *HashMap* which can be accessed by a *String*:

```
private Map<String, Component> components = new HashMap<String, Component>();
```

The problem is that my root *Component* class looks like this:

```
public class Component {

}
```

I feel as if I've headed in the wrong direction so my question is do I need a *Component* super class? If so, is there anything that needs to be put in it? If not, should I have a *HashMap* of *Objects* instead? Are there advantages to either methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component base-class seems to be empty now, but it's just a question of time until you will find functionality to add to it. A good candidate might be an `update()` function which you likely want to have on almost any kind of component.

In the meantime you might want to change it to an interface. That would make it a pure [marker interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern): An interface which defines no functionality, but marks classes which fulfill some specific purpose or implement some contract, like in your case, being a component.

And by the way: If you want to allow one component per component-type on each entity, you might want to define your hash map as a `Map<Class, Component>`. You addComponent method would then do this:

```
public void addComponent(Component newComponent) {
     components.put(newComponent.getClass(), newComponent);
}
```

GetComponent looks like this:

```
public Component getComponent(Class type) {
    return components.get(type);
}
```

and would be called like this:

```
getComponent(PlayerControllerComponent.class);
```

This should be a bit faster and gives you the advantage of type-safety (you can no longer misspell your component identification strings).

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast reply and that marker interface concept is pretty much exactly what I need for that class. Also, having a Map that can be accessed with classes that extend Component seems to be a much more secure way of storing components. :)